# How can I create a single log-in and profile for a network of three sites using Django?

Tags: python, django, pinax

How can I create a single log-in and profile for a network of three sites using Django?

I have a network of three sites and instead of having the user create a profile at each of the three sites, I'd like the user to only need to register one time, and then be able to use all three.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: how do you three sites work currently? Are they *completely independent*/*have similar structure*/*share some other data too*? Are you trying to achieve something like stackoverflow?

Comment: Each site is basically independent, although they each might end up sharing some data. After reading the "sites" doc it does seem like that is the best solution.  I think the key for me is figuring out a way that it looks like a "network" id to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the sites share the databases. Hence they will have a common user table.

Take a look at the django sites framework: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your server(s).

Do all the sites have access to the same DB?  Then use dcrodjer's answer.

If not, you can implement a OAuth style Single Signon Service, that the other sites authenticate against.

Ex:
site1.example.com
site2.example.com
site3.example.com
siteN.example.com

Would auth against oauth.example.com

Answer (score 0):

If you can put those three sites into subdomains of a single domain, then I'm almost sure you can stick to what Django offers. What I'm writing about is something like this:

site1.mydomain.com 
site2.mydomain.com 
site3.mydomain.com

-- where login is implemented at mydomain.com.

Basically, mydomain.com should serve a small Django page that implements only the login form and maintains session for [".mydomain.com" domain](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) (note the leading dot - it's required for the session to propagate to site1..3 subdomains). So if you log into mydomain.com, you're effectively logged into all three subsites.

And the easiest way to share server-side auth and session data is to make ubsites 1,2,3 use two databases, one small database shared with mydomain.com for auth and session data, and the other one specific to given site.